# Textdomain Wordpress Function Doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new on Wordpress, for my father that he wanted a woocommerce website, i've trying to use a template from Themeforest, after a long setup and style the css like we need.
Before to upload on my server, I have a problem on a plugin.
For the moment, my website is in local server, the plugin add a social membership login.
But... I have translate it in French with LocoTranslate, but the translation not show up!
I've tried everything i've found on the web (like stackoverflow), but nothing appear again...

The plugin is specified from the template, but the textdomain function is apparently good.

You can check the code here :

```
    **
    require_once 'load.php';

    if ( ! function_exists( 'qode_membership_text_domain' ) ) {
    /**
     * Loads plugin text domain so it can be used in translation
     */
    function qode_membership_text_domain() {
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'qode_membership', false, QODE_MEMBERSHIP_REL_PATH . '/languages' );
    }

    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'qode_membership_text_domain' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'qode_membership_scripts' ) ) {
```

I don't understand why... But my translation doesn't show.
How we can explain that ?

My folder of the plugin:

[image]

Thank you in advance with your help.